# Prove that every cycle graph $C_{n}$ contains ${n}$ spanning trees?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to come up with a proof for every cycle graph ($C_{n}$) contains (${n}$) spanning trees. I know how to explain it in plain language, and visually, but I'm having a hard time with the notation, or which is the best way to go about proving it?

Does anyone have a good proof of this or know where to start looking? Its not for an assignment, just for a study sheet to have.

Comment: There are $n$ edges, and removing an edge yields a spanning tree...

Comment: Yeah, that seemed more like the plain language explanation I already knew. I didnt know if there was something more sophisticated than that, yet less complex than the answer below.

Comment: @Math1000 I guess you also need a proof that there aren't any other spanning trees. (Something on the lines - if you remove no edges, it is not a tree; if you remove two adjacent edges, you don't cover the vertex between them; if you remove two non-adjacent edges, you don't have a connected subgraph anymore.)

Comment: Do you know that $G$ with $n$ vertices is a tree if and only if $G$ is connected and has $n-1$ edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert but had a quick Google search, and as soon as I found that there was such a thing as Kirchoff's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem), I thought it would be fun to use *that* theorem. (Seems like overkill, but there you go.)

The Laplacian matrix of this graph is:

$$L_n=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&0&\cdots&-1\\-1&2&-1&\cdots&0\\0&-1&2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\-1&0&0&\cdots&2\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

(All nodes of degree 2, each node adjacent to the previous and the next one.) By Kirchoff's theorem, the spanning tree number $t_n$ is given as any cofactor of this matrix, i.e. (by calculating the cofactor corresponding to the upper left corner, i.e. cross out first row and columin in $L_n$) as:

$$t_n =D_{n-1}=\begin{vmatrix}2&-1&0&\cdots&0\\-1&2&-1&\cdots&0\\0&-1&2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&2\end{vmatrix}_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}$$

Now, the above is a determinant of a tri-diagonal matrix, and it is easy to derive recurrence relation:

$$D_n=2D_{n-1}-D_{n-2}$$

(expand on the first row, and then one of the remaining smaller determinants on the first column). Having in mind that $D_1=2$ and $D_2=3$, one can use induction to prove that $D_n=n+1$, which then yields the result $t_n=D_{n-1}=n$.

Comment: I think this is outside my knowledge range... but I appreciate it!

Comment: +1 for applying the beautiful Kirchoff's theorem.  Although it's definitely overkill for this problem, as you say.  A good example of an [awfully sophisticated proof for a simple fact](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts).